# Why does it look different on different devices? Kivy

Tags: python, linux, kivy

I wrote an application on a PC and then compiled for android, but the result is different.

I need the python code to look the way it really is.

***Yes, I know that different devices have different pixel densities, will someone tell me how to solve my problem?***

[image]

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class Test1(Screen):
    pass
class Test2(Screen):
    pass

kvfile = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kvfile

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name

MainApp().run()
```

main.kv:

```
<Test1>:
FloatLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: hex('#D8D8D8')
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 565
            size: 1500, 2
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 48
            size: 1500, 2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: hex('#ffffff')
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'center_x': .5}
        size_hint_y: .055
        Label:
            text: 'ABC'
            bold: True
            background_color: hex('#ECEDF1')
            color: hex('#2D2E30')
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': .92, 'center_x': .5}
        size_hint_y: .82
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                row_default_height: 50
                height: self.minimum_height
                Label:
                    text: '  A'
                    bold: True
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Button:
                    text: "  B"
                    bold: True
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_down: ''
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Button:
                    text: "  C"
                    bold: True
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_down: ''
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Button:
                    text: "  D"
                    bold: True
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_down: ''
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Button:
                    text: "  E"
                    bold: True
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_down: ''
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Button:
                    text: "  F"
                    bold: True
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_down: ''
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Button:
                    text: "  G"
                    bold: True
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_down: ''
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Label:
                    text: "  H"
                    bold: True
                    background_color: hex('#ECEDF1')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Button:
                    text: "  I"
                    bold: True
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_down: ''
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Button:
                    text: "  J"
                    bold: True
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_down: ''
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'
                Button:
                    text: "  K"
                    bold: True
                    background_normal: ''
                    background_down: ''
                    background_color: hex('#ffffff')
                    color: hex('#2D2E30')
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'left'
                    valign: 'middle'

    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': .08, 'center_x': .5}
        size_hint_y: .08
        Button:
            text: 'A'
            bold: True
            background_normal: ''
            background_down: ''
            background_color: hex('#ECEDF1')
            color: hex('#2D2E30')
            on_press:
                app.change_screen('test1')
        Button:
            text: 'B'
            bold: True
            background_normal: ''
            background_down: ''
            background_color: hex('#ECEDF1')
            color: hex('#2D2E30')
            on_press:
                app.change_screen('test2')
```

Answer (score 1):

So you got the basic idea right. It is the dp that is actually causing those letters to bunch together.

Kivy offers a large amount of measurement units you can use to position and resize your widgets in kivy. Currently most of your code is using just pixel size( Your specifying the amount of pixels directly) which for a small program is good enough. But once your program has to scale across multiple devices those pixel units will not be enough.

In this case u can use the dp units in order to position the widgets better.

Rather than

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    row_default_height: 50
    height: self.minimum_height
```

just add

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    row_default_height: 50dp
    height: self.minimum_height
```

i.e. add dp behind the value of row_default_height. The values wont be exact, you may have to change them to get the original position back.
You can get more info from here https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html